Why is SpaceX's whole space suit pressurized and not only the head/neck/shoulders?
Vacuums are much harsher than I thought.]1 Having watched the first first SpaceX space suit test aka. "spacewalk", I finally did more than just reminiscing about Heinlein's "Have space suit will travel." and have spent some hours reading up about space suits,
The Bioastronauticsdata Book seems to indicate that you have singular seconds fix your suit and that you need around 3 psi or 21 kPa to 'respirate', and that getting rid of heat generated by the human body is probably the biggest challenge of a space suit. (I'm sure the body can help...?) But for the most part, everything I read just leaves me with even more questions, surrounding the core idea of only selectively pressurizing a space suit:
So I was wondering why SpaceX didn't opt for a Mechanical Counter-pressure suit for the rest of the body? (MIT's Biosuit seems to have part of it solved.)
Perhaps the way to answer this would be to focus on the major challenges of such suits - and the pros and cons. There is already a lot of information about such suits both on here, and Wikipedia, but nothing that brings it all together, concisely.
Some challenges I've picked up on are trying to separate the helmet and the suit without choking the wearer, or giving them under-arm-hickies... but I haven't found any studies or discussions about some sort of padded- or selectively pressurised helmet-harness. (Think the bladder that is inside watersports gear, like kites or SUPs. I guess a big pro would be not being prone to punctures, or a challenge might be creating some sort of self-healing material.) Surely we've got the required technology and engineering by now?
Or does the SpaceX suit in fact have some counter-pressure properties already?

Welcome to space stackexchange! Consider doing some reading to see what a good question post looks like. You have many separate questions in this post. Consider editing it to get down to one instead of asking for someone to write a book about EVA suit design, or just ask for a reference.

There is a valid question here with an edit to a single question, possibly also seeing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_counterpressure_suit. One boring issue is that you can test an ordinary space suit in a vacuum chamber empty and if it holds pressure before putting a human inside. The only way to test a counter pressure suit is with a human inside, and each failure will be deeply dangerous. Note if you have your head at one atmosphere and your other end at vacuum your gut contents will tend to be forced out.

@GremlinWranger for more on those: What ever happened with that pressure suit design based on elastic tension in contact with skin?

As already noted, there are good questions (plural) in here, but the way StackExchange works a question should only focus on a single topic. Please do  write one or more new questions, each focusing on one topic!

@GremlinWranger A space suit would not bet  tested with a pressure of one atmosphere inside, a vacuum outside and a human in the suit.

@uwe For a suit using a mechanical counter pressure setup I suspect testing without the human it is designed for inside is hard, since their body is a key mechanical part of the structure. Not impossible, but much harder than a conventional suit that you can just run up to pressure empty.

@DarkDust I tried but the moderation on here...... had one of those closed in favor of reopening this one. The questions are more of a "train of thought", the actual question is in the title.
